# Is there a way to manually lock/unlock a table row in PostgreSQL that does not rely on transactions?

Tags: database, postgresql, locking

I am new to database locking, so please bear with me.

I have my SELECT statements in one file, and my UPDATE statements in another. Both make a connection at the start of the file, then disconnect at the end. What I am trying to do is lock the table row in the select statement, and if the user cancels or updates, release that lock.

I have tried advisory locks, but they unlock when I disconnect. All other locks that I tried do the same.

Is there a way that I can achieve what I want in my current DB structure, or do I need to rewrite the whole thing or brute force it with things like row_locked named boolean columns in my DB?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to persist that information across transactions and sessions, then yes, you need a column that stores that information.

I wouldn't use a `boolean` though, but a nullable `timestamp` column so that you can see *when* the row was locked (`null` means "not locked", `not null` means "locked"). This is very useful to cleanup "abandoned locks".

Comment: Design for failure ;-)  Because one day something goes wrong and records become locked forever.

Comment: Thanks for answering and the suggestion! That is what I will do then :)